# an arc is not a retraction of the Klein bottle

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I want to use homology to solve the following problem: Prove that the circle represented by the blue arc in the picture is not a retract of the Klein bottle. (See the attached picture of the Klein bottle)

I know the $q$-th singular homology module of the Klein bottle $K$, and some about singular homology, for example relative homology, MV-sequence, and so on. At first I tried to use the following: If $A$ is a retract of $X$ then $H_q(X) = H_q(A)\oplus H_q(X,A)$. But it does not seem to be helpful for this problem. Do I miss something simple?

Thank you for help!

[image: the Klein bottle]

Comment: Very related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478803/homework-the-klein-bottle-retracts-onto-a-loop?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's because $H_1(A)=\Bbb Z$ is generated by $[a]$, while $H_1(K)$ is $\Bbb Z_2\oplus \Bbb Z$, where $\Bbb Z_2$ is generated by $[a]$ and $\Bbb Z$ is generated by $[b]$. So if $A$ were a retract of $K$, then we would have an injection
$$H_1(A)=\langle[a]\rangle\hookrightarrow H_1(K)=⟨[a],[b]⟩$$
sending $[a]$ to $[a]$, which is impossible since $[2a]=0$ in $H_1(K)$.

Comment: Darn, beat me by about half a minute. +1 :)

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! so I actually missed something really simple.. haha